# How could a hot lander enter Titan's atmosphere without setting its hydrocarbons ablaze?

Tags: reentry, atmosphere, lander, atmospheric-drag, titan

Whenever a lander enters an atmosphere, it generates a lot of friction and that heats up the heat shield. On Earth we have seen videos of spacecraft with red-hot shields.

On Saturn's moon Titan, wouldn't the ignition of some of those hydrocarbons kick-start a run-away inferno?

How can fast moving meteorite not do the same?

Comment: It's not friction that generates heat, it's mostly compression heating as far as I remember...

Comment: In truth, Earth is the weird planet. Most planets don't have readily available supplies of an oxidizer in their atmospheres. You're not going to "burn" methane without an oxidizer, such as oxygen. If Titan's atmosphere did have plenty of free oxygen, it wouldn't have a methane atmosphere - if it evolved similar to ancient Earth, it would most likely have a mix of water, carbon dioxide and oxygen.

Comment: If this were a real risk, the first meteorite to come along would have caused it ...

Comment: Is it possible for another atmospheric component other than oxygen to act as an oxidizer?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

In order for a combustion process to happen, you do not only need fuel, you also need an [oxidizer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Oxidizing_agent). On Earth, that is usually the oxygen in the air. In Titan's atmosphere, there is no oxygen. This applies to other atmospheres too, like the hydrogen dominated atmospheres of Jupiter and Saturn. Hydrogen, just like the methane in Titan's atmosphere, is flammable too, but only in the combination with oxygen.

Basic check, the fire triangle:

[image: fire triangle]

For a meteor impacting Titan:

- Fuel: YES
- Heat: YES
- Oxygen: NO

Comment: Just to add: it would be virtually impossible for any planet or moon to sustain an atmosphere containing significant quantities of both oxygen and hydrocarbons for very long. Sooner or later ignition would occur and after the explosion the body would then be left with a very boring atmosphere of carbon dioxide and water vapour. Alternatively if oxygen and hydrocarbons were building up slowly in an atmosphere, they might react unspectacularly through slower noncombustion reactions (UV catalysed for example) before they got to the concentrations that could cause ignition.

Comment: Though we should note that any outside observer would conclude that Earth has a very unusual non-equilibrium atmosphere with an enormous concentration of oxygen.

Comment: @MarkAdler Earth's atmosphere is perfectly stable with respect to reactions with itself; biological activity removes carbon and sequesters it (ultimately as oil/coal/natural gas.) It'd be interesting to see what "weather" we had if there were huge periodic releases of methane capable of producing vast explosions, potentially more dramatic than forest fires. Europa has mostly O2 atmosphere from the reaction 2H2O --> O2 + 2H2 (H2 lost to space as molecular velocity exceeds escape velocity) but that mechanism wouldn't work for Earth so Earth's O2 rich atmosphere would indeed stand out as unusual.

Comment: To follow up on @LevelRiverSt's comment, one of the proposed strategies for looking for extraterrestrial life is to look for planets whose atmospheric spectra contain unusually high levels of oxygen. Because oxygen is so reactive, any planet with large amounts of it in the atmosphere must have some process to replenish it, which might indicate the existence of photosynthetic life.

Comment: @LevelRiverSt, most of the Earth's original CO2 is locked up as various calcites (chalk, limestone, & marble).

Comment: @LevelRiverSt: Methane is a greenhouse gas much stronger than CO2. There were plans to seal the oil leak under the Gulf of Mexico with nuclear charges - and they were forfeited with extreme prejudice; risk of releasing the huge methane deposits which would be a global extinction event, temperature rising above livable levels.

Comment: BillOer yes Earth has huge reserves of CO2. Dissolved oceanic CO2 is more "dynamically available" (and is increasing in recent times due to injection of so much more CO2 into the atmosphere by burning fossil fuels.) But plants do an excellent job of converting nearly all available atmospheric CO2 into the reactive chemical O2, generating organic carbon in the process. @SF yes there'd be global warming too, possibly enough to make Earth unliveable anyway. But runaway global warming is well known on Venus. Giant naturally occuring gas explosions are completely unknown & potentially very dramatic

Comment: @LevelRiverSt And it doesn't even require an outright ignition. Tiny amounts of the fuel and oxidizer will react even if ignition temperature isn't reached, and over time, this can replace the whole atmosphere. This is likely how Earth's methane atmosphere slowly converted to a water + carbon dioxide atmosphere. The reaction is still the same as with burning, of course - scale is the main difference. The same way, with huge releases of methane, you most likely wouldn't get much spectacle - it wouldn't burn or explode easily, unless you provided an ignition source etc.

Comment: @SF. It's more like "we couldn't calculate if it would be a real issue or not, so we're taking the safer approach and using a technique we know is going to work". It's very hard to estimate global effects of something like this, especially when you don't even know how much methane would realistically be released and how long it would survive in the atmosphere (needless to say, methane has some trouble surviving in an atmosphere with plenty of free oxygen). Not to mention judging how much of the methane would be disrupted by the blast itself etc. - it's a very complex problem, really.

Comment: @Luaan: You do get naturally occuring coal and gas fires, e.g. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Burning_Mountain and https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yanarta%C5%9F

Comment: @jamesqf Sure, I didn't want to imply that the only possible source of the ignition is human intervention :D You do get "spontaneous" ignition under certain conditions (wet hay is one of the quite typical examples), and there's plenty of ignition sources on Earth, with or without humans. Still, those fires were most likely ignited by something at one point (a wildfire, lightning, volcanic activity, ...) and have been burning ever since. The question is more like "will it reach an ignition source while it still has the concentration to continuously burn/explode?".

Comment: This, indeed; for a different perspective on it, you may be interested in my question [How can I destroy a gas giant planet?](http://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/q/10150/29) on [worldbuilding.se]. The accepted (and one of the two currently highest net voted) answer specifically mentions the problem of oxidizer.

Comment: interesting, what if you went to a hydrocarbon lake with a huge oxygen tank and ignited it?

Comment: @PirateApp It will burn, potentially very quickly, until the oxygen in the tank is depleted. Then the reaction would stop.